# Http Status 200 to response back to third party

Tags: vb.net, http-status-code-200

I am currently working on the payment gate way which connects to Third Party Payment API by giving some information including return_url (that they will send the payment result back) and notify_url (that send the same information as in return_url in case there are some issues with the cardholders' internet connection or issues with their browser).

After processing at their end, my end processed return page and notification  page successfully.

But they said as follows.

> Merchant would have to response with HTTP 200 OK to indicate that the notification is received successfully.
>   They would retry (up to 5 times) to resend the notification again if HTTP 200 OK response is not received after specific timeout (currently is fixed to 60 seconds timeout).

So I put the following codes in the notification page.

```
If Response.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK Then
    Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
End If
```

I think this snippets aren't enough because they are still calling to my notification page 4 times. 
I check the log tables. Although the process is complete, the log are still coming in after some interval.

Anybody can help about to response with HTTP Status 200 .

Any suggestion are appreciated.

Comment: HttpStatusCode.OK is 200, isn't it ?

Comment: As long as there are no errors in processing your Paypal IPN handler then the web server should kick out a HTTP 200 Status all on its own.